# javascript - button needs to be click twice for onclick to trigger

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

Why does my button need to be clicked twice for the onclick event to trigger? 
There're some other thread on stackoverflow with the same problem, but in all the thread i found, the original poster puts the event handler inside the function. It's not like that with my code.

Html

```
<body>
    <ul id="parentList">
        <li>First child</li>
        <li>Second child</li>
        <li>Third child</li>
        <li>Forth child</li>
        <li>Fifth child</li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" id="delete">Delete first child</button>
</body>
```

Script:

```
var parentList = document.getElementById("parentList");
document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() {
    parentList.removeChild(parentList.firstChild);
};
```

Demonstration: [onclick-error](https://jsfiddle.net/morgianna1802/ofLvac32/1/)

Comment: Did you try defining parentList in the function?

Comment: @FelixHäberle What do u mean?? It needs to be clicked twice, but the <li> child does get removed, so the browser must recognize parentList isn't it?

Comment: I think parentList is out of scope at the first click. Copy your first js line into the function.

Comment: @FelixHäberle what do you mean that `parentList` is out of scope?

Comment: Why not use `firstElementChild` instead? That way you can be sure you're removing an element, not a text node. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first "element" within the parentList is whitespace. You can see this by console logging the element within the event listener.

[image: whitespace example]

You therefore need to only filter out the `li` elements within the parent item.

```
document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() {
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#parentList > li");

    if (listItems.length > 0) {
        listItems[0].remove();
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ofLvac32/13/

You could also use `parentList.firstElementChild` **instead of** `parentList.firstChild`, which filters out any invalid nodes (whitespace).

**An example of this**

```
var parentList = document.getElementById("parentList");

document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() {
    parentList.removeChild(parentList.firstElementChild);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ofLvac32/37/

Comment: There's also the [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) method. Also be aware that `childNode.remove()` is not supported in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll add this to the answer as an alternative solution! I didn't know this

Answer (score 1):

With `elementChild`, you look for *any* child, including white spaces.

You could use `parentList.firstElementChild` instead to get the first child *element*.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your click handler on the button. The problem is with the way you are removing the first child. If you add this small change to  your function:

```
var parentList = document.getElementById("parentList");
    document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() {
    console.log(parentList.removeChild(parentList.firstChild));
};
```

You will notice that the first click logs out some empty spaces with a line break. This appears to be an empty text node. The second click removes the first `<li>` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

As you could see in following snippet, first child is string of new line and spaces:

```js
function loaded(){
  document.getElementById("parentList");
  var firstChild = parentList.firstChild;
  console.log("First child: \"" + firstChild.data + "\"");
}
```

```html
<body onload="javascript:loaded()">
 <ul id="parentList">
  <li>First child</li>
  <li>Second child</li>
  <li>Third child</li>
  <li>Forth child</li>
  <li>Fifth child</li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

You could use [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) property to get only the first child Element, like:

```js
var parentList = document.getElementById("parentList");
document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() {  parentList.removeChild(parentList.firstElementChild);
};
```

```html
<ul id="parentList">
    <li>First child</li>
    <li>Second child</li>
    <li>Third child</li>
    <li>Forth child</li>
    <li>Fifth child</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="delete">Delete first child</button>
```